# SQL Server : create Excel file in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, excel, t-sql, pdf

I want to create an Excel file by typing T-SQL into SQL Server. I'm just getting your attention. I don't want to create with mouse, I want to create by writing code. How can I do it? It can also be a pdf file, no problem.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this command to export data to an Excel file:

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Excel 12.0;Database=C:\Exportedfiles\Data.xlsx;','SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')

SELECT * FROM dbo.yourTableName
```

also you can use this article( part two :Export SQL Server data to an Excel file using T-SQL code in middle of article) to learn all thing about this.[Articl Link](https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/how-to-import-and-export-sql-server-data-to-an-excel-file/)